# PHP get largest number from 3 variables

Tags: php, numbers, highest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return variable with the highest value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737305/return-variable-with-the-highest-value)

I'm trying to come up with a simple way of finding the highest number out of 3 variables.

```
$1 = 100
$2 = 300
$3 = 200
```

out of those 3 variables, I want to set a new variable as the highest one ($2)

so:

```
$highest_number = 300
```

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$highest_number = max($1, $2, $3);
```

OR

```
$values = array($1, $2, $3);
$highest_number = max($values);
```

Additional information can be found at [the quickref for max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this however it returns "Array" instead of the number. :\

Comment: Should be `array_max($values)` for the array version.

Comment: @Michael From the PHP Docs: *If the first and only parameter is an array, max() returns the highest value in that array. If at least two parameters are provided, max() returns the biggest of these values.*

Comment: @DylanCross this is definitely the right way to do it. $1, $2 or $3 must be an array. Try `var_dump(max($values));` in order to see waht exactly is in the array.