# Get name of variable with highest integer from list Python 3.3.4

Tags: python, list

Recently tried something similar to [PHP get largest number from 3 variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876000/php-get-largest-number-from-3-variables)

(In Python's form of course) However when returning the value I get the value of the variable, not the name of the variable.

My array looks like this:

```
x = 1

y = 2

z = 3

alloutputs = [x, y, z]
```

The furthest and most ugliest before needing help is this:

```
alloutputs[alloutputs.index(max(alloutputs))]
```

However it's still giving me an integer of the highest value! How would I get back the name of x, y, or z depending on which is largest?

Comment: Why would you need the name of the variable, as opposed to the value? There's probably a better option, e.g. turning those variables into dictionary entries.

Comment: Variables are just temporary symbols; they have no meaning outside of the algorithm, and the symbol used for them is arbitrary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @zhangxaochen says, you need to use a dictionary or named tuple. You could use a dictionary like this:

```
>>> d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
>>> max(d, key=d.get)
'z'
```

Comment: You mean `max(d, key=d.get)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice on dictionaries, this is still quick for my needs and works great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A list does not save the names of variables. Use a dictionary or [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
In [296]: d=dict(x=1, y=2, z=3)

In [297]: from operator import itemgetter
     ...: max(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
     ...: 
Out[297]: 'z'
```

Comment: `sorted(...)[-1]` is a silly way to spell `max(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
alloutputs = ["x", "y", "z"]
print max(alloutputs, key = locals().get)
```

However, if you ever really have to do this, you might want to reconsider your design, IMHO.

Comment: It turns into perfectly good design when you use a proper, separate dictionary in place of `locals()`.

Comment: @delnan You mean, depending on the variable's name is considered a good design?

Comment: Not at all. I'm talking about when it *isn't* a variable name, simply a dictionary key (and most likely not hard-coded but coming from a dynamic data source).

Comment: @delnan But OP is trying to get the variable's name which has got the maximum value. That is why I want him to reconsider the design.

Comment: I concur, I already told OP the same thing in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** this is terrible and you should not do this.

```
[var for var in dir() if eval(var) == max(all)][0]
```

It does what you want but - as others have said - you would be much better off using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary:

```
alloutputs = {'x':1,'y':2,'z':3}
maxvalue = max(alloutputs.values())
print [k for k, v in alloutputs.iteritems() if v == maxvalue]
```

Comment: Looping over a dictionary is like clubbing someone to death with a loaded Uzi. Use the `key` parameter of `max`, e.g. `max(alloutputs, key=alloutputs.get)` or something to that effect.